# Draw graph from QSqlQueryModel on QML Canvas, refresh

Tags: database, qt, canvas, qml

Application based on Qt 5.2 and QML. Got a database, querying it from a class inheriting from `QSqlQueryModel`. Using a QML `TableView` with the model set to an instance of that class. Using `model.query().exec()` to refresh the `TableView` on demand.

Now I need to do the same with a QML `Canvas`. `Canvas.onPaint` will go through the model using `model.get(index)` and draw using `Canvas.getContext("2d")`. But how can I make the Canvas redraw everything when the model changes its data (i.e. by `model.query().exec()`)?

I failed to find any information how to get some "data changed" signal from the model, and how to make the Canvas clear redraw everything.

I can not change this setup, especially not the Qt version. Data has to come from the database via a class inheriting from `QSqlQueryModel`, and data has to be drawn on a `Canvas`.

Comment: What about `requestPaint`? You could imperatively call it after `model.query().exec()` to force a repaint of your drawing region.

Comment: Not exactly what I had in mind, because `model.query().exec()` is actually hidden in the `QSqlQueryModel`-based class. But it should be easy to `emit` a signal from there and connect that to the canvas. I will test that.

Comment: Emitting a signal should work like a charm. Be sure to call `clearRect` before `requestPaint` if your paint code just draws on the `Canvas`.